# Trouble setting timeout for Nagios test

Tags: ssh, configuration, oracle, nagios, timeout

I have Nagios monitoring an Oracle installation on a different server.  Sometimes one particular test (check oracle tablespace can allocate next extent) will fail with "CRITICAL - Plugin timed out after 10 seconds".

The first thing I want to do is figure out how long it actually takes to complete.  If it's 11 seconds, maybe I don't care, and I just want to set the timeout a little higher.

I tried setting the timeout for check_by_ssh, which is used to run the actual command, like so:

```
define command {
  command_name    check_ssh_oracle_health
  command_line    $USER1$/check_by_ssh -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C 
      "/export/home/nagios/libexec/check_oracle_health --mode=$ARG1$ --environment 
      ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1 
      --connect=nagios/<pwd>@<SID> --timeout=15"
}
```

This had no effect; the test still errors out, and still says it happened after 10 seconds (and yes, I did restart Nagios :).

The only other place I can see to set a timeout is in nagios.cfg; that seems like too high-level (it would affect all tests) and besides, none of them are currently set to 10 seconds so I doubt this is the right place.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is the `check_by_ssh` that's timing out (10 seconds is the default timeout for this check) and not the `check_oracle_health` inside it.  Try to set the timeout of `check_by_ssh` to a higher value and see if it still happens.

Hope this helps!

Comment: add the following arg to check_by_ssh with the appropriate value 

 -t, --timeout=INTEGER
    Seconds before connection times out (default: 10)

Comment: Glad it helped. :)